# Disable Accept-encoding:gzip for specific website firefox

Tags: firefox, headers

There is a website which right now is failing when using gzip encoding.

The site works fine when using `Accept-encoding: deflate`, I found that this can be done by using the global setting: [network.http.accept-encoding](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.http.accept-encoding), but would not like to disable it globally.

- It seems like it was possible by installing [Modify Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/modify-headers/) extension, but the extension is not available anymore.

Is there any way to disable gzip encoding for specific site without installing an extension?